# Unable to infer url for tomcat jdk11-openjdk-buster docker image

Tags: docker, tomcat, amazon-ecs, swagger-ui, springfox

For a spring boot application I was using the docker image `tomcat:jdk11-openjdk-buster` from 24-Aug-2021 and the swagger-ui.html would load properly.

Today if I build the Dockerfile again with absolutely no changes to the code or Dockerfile, the swagger-ui.html gives,
[image]

The weird thing is if I do a `curl -I http://xyzxyz.com/warfile/swagger-ui.html` I still get 200

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Date: Fri, 17 Dec 2021 14:16:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 3381
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Sun, 14 Jan 2018 16:12:50 GMT
```

I'm convinced something in the docker image has changed. My initial thought going through the issue list at https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/issues/252 was maybe the http request is redirecting to https.
But if that were the case wouldn't curl give http 302 instead of a 200?

Is there a way I can know changes made to `tomcat:jdk11-openjdk-buster` image since August?

If it helps I use path based routing using AWS application load balancer, ECS service and container instance as environment

Answer (score 0):

I checked the [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/layers/tomcat/library/tomcat/jdk11-openjdk-buster/images/sha256-be5cf7ad5d4f85da69d3848316d31d21df4cea30ec888445a863d49bec3b8d27) for `tomcat:jdk11-openjdk-buster` and realised the tomcat version has been upgraded from 9.x.x to 10.x.x which was causing my app to not run.

So had to change the base image to `tomcat:9-jdk11-openjdk` which will at least fix the Tomcat version to 9.x.x and openjdk to 11.x.x